# emacs interactive python shell shows no feedback

Tags: python, emacs

In my terminal shell if I just evaluate, e.g. `3+3`, I get

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, May 21 2017, 04:38:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3+3
6
>>>
```

However, using emacs' interactive shell and when evaluating code using  `python-shell-send-line` or `python-shell-send-region`, I don't get any feedback on the code being executed (unless of course there is some `print` involved).

my relevant configuration in `.emacs` is just this:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/opt/local/bin/python3.6"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i")
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'anaconda-mode)
```

I'm not sure whether it is related, but even though I do have `readline` installed (as you can see in the image), I also get this warning:

```
Warning (python): Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline, yet ‘python-shell-completion-native’ was t and "python3.6" is not part of the ‘python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters’ list.  Native completions have been disabled locally.
```

[image]

I'd like to see some feedback on the code I execute. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following bound to <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>.  It is just a simple hack to send a print statement if the line doesn't start with one, YMMV.

```
;; send current line, with prefix print result
(defun python--send-line (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (not arg)
      (python-shell-send-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line)
      (if (looking-at-p "\\s-*print")
          (python-shell-send-region (line-beginning-position)
                                    (line-end-position))
        (python-shell-send-string
         (concat "print(" (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                            (line-end-position))
                 ")")))))
  (display-buffer (process-buffer (python-shell-get-process))))
```